# How to assign prototype to generic type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to build a sessionStorage service that can parse objects strings to a generic type. but with this implementation it only returns an object without prototype (no object functions).

here is the code:

```
public static getObject<T>(key: string): T{

    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key)) as T;
}
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not encode functions, or prototypes, or constructors. Parsed JSON will never create an instance of any class for you. It's just raw structured data. And this is true for most ways that you might serialize javascript data.

There is no good way around that. It's up to you to structure your codebase so that things will work with this in mind.

There are an innumerable number of solutions to this, but for example you could pass this data to a constructor after you fetch it.

Something like this:

```
const data = sessionStorageInstance.getObject<MyInterfaceHere>('some/key')
const instance = new MyClassHere(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, generic type only happens in TypeScript as some kind of model design assistance. It will never be compiled into JavaScript file. Take your sessionStorage service as an example:

```js
// SessionStorageService.ts
class SessionStorageService {
  public static getObject<T>(key: string): T{
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key)) as T;
  }
}
```

If we compile above TypeScript file into JavaScript using `tsc`, we can find `T` is completely removed:

```js
// SessionStorageService.js
var SessionStorageService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function SessionStorageService() {
    }
    SessionStorageService.getObject = function (key) {
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    };
    return SessionStorageService;
}());
```

To return object with class/prototype in deserialization, you need to save class/prototype information during serialization. Otherwise, these class/prototype information will be lost.

I've made an npm module named [esserializer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esserializer) to solve this problem automatically: save JavaScript class instance values during serialization, in plain JSON format, together with its class name information. Later on, during the deserialization stage (possibly in another process or on another machine), esserializer can recursively deserialize object instance, with all Class/Property/Method information retained, using the same class definition. For your SessionStorageService, it would look like:

```js
// SessionStorageService.ts
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
ESSerializer.registerClasses([ClassA, ClassB]); //register all classes possibly involved in serialization.

class SessionStorageService {
  public static getObject(key: string){
    return ESSerializer.deserialize(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
  }
}

// Previously, set sessionStorage in another file
const ESSerializer = require('esserializer');
sessionStorage.setItem(key, ESSerializer.serialize(anObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using your code somewhat like this?

```
class SessionStorageManager {
    public static getObject<T>(key: string): T{
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key)) as T;
    }
}

const test = SessionStorageManager.getObject('test');
```

In this example, `T` has no default value set where `getObject` is defined, and I haven't set a type when calling `getObject` either, so the type of `test` according to TypeScript is `unknown`.

If you want to make sure that anything returned by `getObject` is a type of `Object`, then you'll want to use `extends` when creating your generic function to explain this to TypeScript. For example:

```
public static getObject<T extends object>(key: string): T{
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key)) as T;
}
```

However, be wary that the use of `as` here is essentially bypassing the type check. Only do this if you are confident that you will always be getting an object out of `JSON.parse`. Remember that you can still get primitives out of it, in cases such as `JSON.parse('2')` or `JSON.parse("string")`, and if the JSON string is malformed then `JSON.parse` will throw an error.

If you want to be type safe, then you will need to add a type check to support that `as` [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). Depending on how you are using this code, you might need to do that outside the `getObject` function since you might now know what [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) may need to be used to determine whether or not an object really is of the given type of `T`.

To ensure these type guards must be used, you may want to instead have `getObject` return the type `unknown`, which means TypeScript won't let you make any assumptions about the type until you've done some type narrowing. For example:

```
class SessionStorageManager {
    public static getObject(key: string): unknown {
        return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(key));
    }
}

const obj = SessionStorageManager.getObject('test'); // type unknown

if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    // type object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create an empty object with the correct prototype, and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add all of the properties from the JSON data.

Note that you need to pass `cls` as an argument when you call this function, since otherwise there is no way of knowing which class you want to set as the prototype. If the calling code doesn't necessarily know which class the object should be, you could come up with some way to encode this in your `key` (e.g. instead of `someKey` you could make it `YourClass-someKey` and then have a registry of classes so you could look up `YourClass` by name).

```
type ClassOf<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T

function makeObject<T>(cls: ClassOf<T>, json: string): T {
    const obj: T = Object.create(cls.prototype);
    Object.assign(obj, JSON.parse(json));
    return obj;
}
```

Example usage:

```
class Kitten {
    constructor(public name: string) {}
    meow(): void { console.log(this.name + ' says meow!'); }
}

// const mittens: Kitten
const mittens = makeObject(Kitten, '{"name": "Mittens"}');
// Mittens says meow!
mittens.meow();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IPIDMA8AVAfFAXigDsIB3ACgDoaEAnAcyQC4oFiQBtAXQEpD82ALAAoUegCuxAMbAAlgHtiUALYIA1hFQAjAFYRZOXBWlwWsRCgxGANFF1IlrJMDpziDXq2xQA3qKhAqGklFygFPW9CKB19WSppOggEYAgTMyowOgVgHPAIXgBuAKDYg2AqZCQ5BmIKCN07ACkAZVQAOUz6JDSHJV4iksCk4Ak6ZQbikQBfUVFTKqgAaTlgVOV-ESDg0NcJWQU6CjAJbTg5aRIEFQhnV3dPP1mtoJuFSi8oADcFOQATPw7YiOOAQKhwBQMCjAAAWciQVGI12gAGooAByKBIBAgJCqCDvACE6KKUGez1EAHpKUCwipVutzCs1hBiPNdqoGay8UQ1JoyrIKMz1nZ0b4AERIm7i1jigCyXOB4umJKm1KgCpZwKxOLxbzIhNE9K1CP1FEGIiAA)